# Creating a new instance when getting data from service?

Tags: java, list, memory, heap-memory

When we fill a list by retrieving data from a service, we no not create an instance e.g. `List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();`. I am not sure regarding to the actual reason for that.

**1.** In this case our `employees` variable refers to the employee list that had already been allocated when calling `getAllEmployees()` method?

**2.** What if I create a new instance `List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();` and then fill it `employees = getAllEmployees();` ? Is it meaning creatingand allocating unnecessary variable on the memory?

***main:***

```
public void demo() {
    List<Employee> employees = getAllEmployees();
}
```

***service:***

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    return employeeService.findAll();
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure what the question is really, but certainly assigning something to a variable to then immediately reassign is not necessary.

Comment: One step as in `List<Employee> employees = getAllEmployees();` is fine

Comment: Thanks for reply amigos. But, I know it, but what happens when I call just `List<Employee> employees = getAllEmployees();`. In this case I think we do not allocate extra memory space for new list, but where the employee list is kept in this situation? Is it like a pointer approach e.g. updating pointer instead of allocating a new memory?

Comment: The method getAllEmployees() probably allocates a list for you. This is not like C++ where you need to worry about who owns what. The method allocates a list for you, and when you no longer using it, the garbage collector automatically deallocates it.

Comment: In Java objects are created on the heap and all you pass around is a reference (you can think of it as being similar to a smart pointer in C++). So `getAllEmployees()` likely creates the list on the heap and returns a reference. `List<Employee> employees` is another reference that not takes the "value" of the returned reference, i.e. it now refers to the same list. Since objects are created on the heap they're not bound to the scope of the method they have been created in - as long as a _live_ thread can access the list, it will stay on the heap. If that changes the GC can collect it.

Comment: Btw, as a side note lists in Java are also just collections of references as are object arrays. That means that if you create such a list or array there's no memory "allocated" for the elements, just for the references (nowadays typically 8 bytes per reference).

Comment: @Thomas Very good explanations. Just need an extra clarification regarding to your last comment ("*Btw, as a side note lists in Java are also just collections of ...*"). Any comment?

Comment: I'm not sure what extra clarification you want me to provide. Just be aware of the fact that object arrays (those that "contain" objects) are actually just arrays of references which means the elements "contained" in those arrays are located somewhere else on the heap and do not depend on the array. The same extends to lists.

Answer (score 0):

> What if I create a new instance `List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();` and then fill it `employees = getAllEmployees();` ?

> Is it meaning creating and allocating unnecessary variable on the memory?

Yes, it's unnecessary. You create one reference to an empty arraylist, then override the reference to the result of a method return value. This does not "fill" the list.

These solutions fill an existing list while keeping a reference intact

```
// assuming your service returned service list needed to be mutated 
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>(employeeService.findAll());
```

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();  // could be a class instance variable 
employees.clear();  // assuming there's existing data in the list 
employees.addAll(employeeService.findAll());
```